# How can I get the Predictive Interface to work in Slide Show environment?

Tags: slideshows, predictive-interface

It appears as though the predictive interface does not work in the Slide Show screen environment.

Comment: the fastest way is `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],ShowPredictiveInterface->True]`. To make it permanent you need to make your own style sheet in which this is set to true in "SlideShow" environment (by default it is False)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I do have my own style sheet but I haven't been able to figure out how to set this to true in the "Slide Show" environment.  When I edit my style sheet and click on the cell "Local definition for all styles in environment Slide Show" the option ShowPredictiveInterface is not editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "SlideShow"],
 ShowPredictiveInterface->True,
  ShowCodeAssist->True]
```

to your slideshow stylesheet then it will give you the predictive interface -- works for me using OS X 10.9.4 and Mma 9.0.1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I've noticed a bug with the predictive interface on slides after the first one.  What happens to me is that the interface for a command on slide 2 shows up at the to of slide 3.

Comment: @YequalsX I agree it looks like a bug. See my update.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: I'm not able to let the suggestion bar appear in M10 and M11 using the two options as you indicated. Is there any known updates? I would arrange a presentation where I explain the Wolfram Predictive Interface and it's very annoying to switch to Working as ScreenEnvironment during a SlideShow presentation. Thanks

Comment: @bobknight best suggestion I have is have a look at what new options may be controlling what you want to do. You can find them in the options inspector